# Some Font Awesome icons are not working

Tags: html, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <div style="margin-top: 5px">
          <label>
             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                Chat with @Model.MemberFirstName</a>
          </label>
          <label>
             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                Send Friend Request</a>
          </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

Writing this code, I am using 2 **font awesome** icons. My first icon is showing on my output screen but 2nd one is not showing. I have written same code for 2nd. I also try removing the first one, The second still not show.
Here is the output atatched.

[image: output screen]

Comment: are you sure you have the second icon in your set .. try using another .one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

font-awesome v4.0.0 doesn't contain `fa-user-plus` class. Use font-awesome v4.7.0

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12">
     <div style="margin-top: 5px">
          <label>
             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                Chat with @Model.MemberFirstName</a>
          </label>
          <label>
             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                Send Friend Request</a>
          </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your question your are using `fontawesome 4.0.0` version but `fa-user-plus` has come in `fontawesome 4.3`. Check updated snippet below with latest version

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="col-md-12">
     <div style="margin-top: 5px">
          <label>
             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                Chat with @Model.MemberFirstName</a>
          </label>
          <label>
             <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                Send Friend Request</a>
          </label>
     </div>
</div>
```